# Sumar columnas array bidimensional Python

Tags: python

estoy empezando en python y tengo un ejercicio en el que tengo que sumar filas y las columnas de un array bidimensional de 4x6, los números tienen que ser aleatorios entre 1 y 200, lo de sumar las filas lo tengo dominado, pero lo de las columnas no me acaba de salir. Os agradezco cualquier ayuda, código:

```
import random
suma_fila=0
llista=[]

for c in range(4):
    llista.append([])
    for z in range(6):
        num=random.randint(1,200)
        llista[c].append(num)


for i in llista:
    for c in i:
        suma_fila=suma_fila+c
        print(c,end=" ")
    print("|",suma_fila)
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que cambiar el enfoque, pues estas haciendo dos pasadas por la matriz cuando puedes lograrlo todo en una sola pasada.

Declaramos `llista` que contendrá la matriz. Esto no es necesario para producir el resultado impreso, pero lo dejamos por si se necesita la matriz para otro uso. También voy a usar nombres significativos para las variables.

Vamos a crear la matriz por filas, por lo que puedo ir a) imprimiendo la fila y b) calculando el total de la fila en la misma pasada.

Declaro la lista `suma_columnas` que contendra el total por columnas. Voy a ir totalizando las columnas inmediatamente que genere cada nuevo valor para una celda.

```
import random

llista = []
suma_columna = [0] * 6 # => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for fila in range(4):
    suma_fila = 0
    fila_val = [] # Lista de valores de la fila
    for columna in range(6):
        num=random.randint(1,200)
        fila_val.append(num)
        suma_fila += num  # Acumular por fila.
        suma_columna[columna] += num # Acumular por columna

        print(f"{num:4d}", end=" ") # Imprimir un valor con ancho 4
    print("|",suma_fila)
    llista.append(fila_val) # Agregar la fila a la matriz.

print("-" * 35) # Tirar raya para la suma
for columna in range(6):
    print(f"{suma_columna[columna]:4d}", end=" ")
```

produce:

```
 157   13   28   93   89  180 | 560
  23  159   36  105    1   81 | 405
 112  135   34  197   47  140 | 665
 108   17  142  193  192   73 | 725
-----------------------------------
 400  324  240  588  329  474
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por explicarlo. A veces me cuesta llegar a un objetivo y empiezo a mezclar cosas haciendo el programa.